# Create a Chatter Post

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, chatter

I am trying to use Journey Builder to create a Chatter post in order to notify a SF user of a required action.

I could not find any docs available and in JB you can only find something called Chatter Extension.

I've tried it and injected someone in the journey:
[image]

But I could not find it in Salesforce. I have no idea where it went...

Anyone ever tried to do this? Is it doable? My plan B would be to use a Task but I want to explore the Chatter path first.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce support confirmed what I was thinking, it is not possible:

> Hello Jeremy, how are you?
>
> My name is Daniel from Salesforce Support Team and I took ownership of
>   your case.
>
> I would like to inform you that Journey Builder does not create
>   Chatter posts or has any activity for this use case.
>
> You can check all Journey Builder canvas activities in our article:
>   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_canvas_activities.htm&type=5

I guess that if you leverage process builder or something specific to the CRM maybe it is doable but not directly in JB.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality out of the box.

Consider to use [Custom Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm) to implement that functionality. The process is a bit complicated but eventually you can develop almost any functionality, since custom activity its external application that connected to Journey Builder.

Check this video for more details: [Create Your Own Journey Builder Activities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbaUkhdtqTQ)